# Mongoose query 8x slower than shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with 200,000+ documents in that I'm filtering with a few where clauses.

Here's my query in Mongoose:

```
 const assets = await GpsLog
                          .where('gps_time')
                          .gte(first)
                          .lte(last)
                          .where('location')
                          .within()
                          .geometry(geoFence);
```

Where `geofence` is a GeoJSON polygon.

The shell query I'm running is:

```
db.gps_log.find({
  'gps_time': {
    $gte: first,
    $lte: last
  },
  'location': {
    '$geoIntersects': {
      '$geometry': {
        'type': 'Polygon',
        'coordinates': // polygon
      }
    }
  }
})
```

The Mongoose query completes in anywhere between 5 to 11 seconds, whereas the shell query completes in 0.5s.

I translated the shell query to execute in Mongoose as:

```
const res = await GpsLog.find({
  'gps_time': {
    $gte: 1539648000,
    $lte: 1539820800
  },
  'location': {
    '$geoIntersects': {
      '$geometry': geoFence
    }
  }
}).lean().exec();
```

But it's still taking 4+ seconds to execute.

Am I missing something with the speed difference?

Comment: Does the shell query also finish in 0.5s when you use `db.gps_log.find(...).toArray()`?

Comment: @robertklep no it doesn't. I'm assuming that's the execution speed of the query that I'm experiencing in Node?

Comment: The Mongo shell returns a cursor, and reads the first 20 results of that cursor, but not the rest, unless you use `.toArray()` to actually read _all_ results. Mongoose reads all results by default.

Comment: @robertklep ah that makes a lot more sense. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mongo shell, when you perform a query, returns a cursor and reads (at most) 20 results from it. After that, you need to exhaust the cursor (read all results) through one of various methods.

So what you're basically testing is how long it takes in the Mongo shell to return a cursor and read 20 results from it. In your case, that takes 0.5s.

However, Mongoose, by default, reads *all* results. So if you want to do a fair comparison between Mongoose and the shell, you should read all the results in the shell as well, for instance by using the [`toArray`](http://www.dba86.com/docs/mongo/3.2/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor.html#iterator-index) method on the cursor:

```
db.gps_log.find({ ... }).toArray()
```

Alternatively, you can ask Mongoose to [return a cursor](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#streaming) instead of reading all results immediately:

```
const cursor = GpsLog.find({ ... }).lean().cursor();

cursor.on('data', doc => { ... }).on('close', () => { ... });
```